# Dependencies issue with lib using third party lib

Tags: kotlin, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have a custom-made library called **LibA** with this `build.gradle.kts`

```kotlin
repositories {
    maven { url = uri("https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots") }
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    ...
    api("org.ta4j:ta4j-core:0.15-SNAPSHOT")
}
```

I need to add `maven { url = uri("https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots") }` in order to resolve the ta4j library.

Then I use **LibA** in my **Project A** with the following `build.gradle.kts`

```kotlin
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("com.example:libA:0.0.1")
}
```

Unfortunately when I do that I get this error:

```
xecution failed for task ':compileKotlin'.
> Error while evaluating property 'filteredArgumentsMap' of task ':compileKotlin'
   > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
      > Could not find org.ta4j:ta4j-core:0.15-SNAPSHOT.
        Required by:
            project : > com.example:libA:0.0.1
```

I don't know what is missing from my **LibA** to make it work. Any help is appreciated